# ValueError: Too many values to unpack, how do I go about fixing this?

Tags: python

So I'm getting the "Too many values to unpack error" and I'm guessing it's because i'm trying to set  " _, _, pile1, pile2" equal to just two variables. But I don't understand why, since I'm already saying to ignore the first two variables shouldn't it just ignore those two and set the rest equal to pile1, pile2?

```
def getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2):
    print("Now it's my turn.")
    pile1, pile2= pile1, pile2
    x= x 
    y= y
    if x==1:
        print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 2")
        pile2= pile2 - y
        pile1= pile1
    elif x==2:
        print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 1")
        pile1= pile1 - y
        pile2= pile2
    return x,y, pile1, pile2

def compPiles(pile1, pile2):
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    pile1, pile2= pile1, pile2
    print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
    print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
    return pile1, pile2

###########MAIN################  
_,_,pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)   
if pile1==0 and pile2==0:
    print("The game is over because I took the last chip.")
    print("Thanks for playing. Let's wager next time.")        

pile1, pile2 = _,_,pile1, pile2

compi= compPiles(pile1, pile2)
```

And I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Yuya\Downloads\homework2.py", line 113, in <module>
pile1, pile2 = _,_,pile1, pile2
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that line?

Comment: Why are you trying to set `pile` and `pile2` to themselves?  That won't accomplish anything.

Comment: `x` and `y` are clearly irrelevant outside `getCompMove`; why do you `return` them *at all?!* And why bother with e.g. `pile2= pile2`, or assigning the `None` that `compPiles` will `return` to `compi`?

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
pile1, pile2 = _,_,pile1, pile2
```

You have two things on the LHS, and you are trying to unpack four. You can't do that, but your objective isn't clear. A solution to your problem requires a better description of it.

Note that in this context, `_` is a variable like any other<sup>*</sup>. So when you say

```
_,_,pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
```

You are reading the first, then the second value in the tuple returned by `getCompMove` into `_`. The end result is that `_` holds the second value. So when you say this:

```
pile1, pile2 = _,_,pile1, pile2
```

you are just trying to read four values into two variables, and as the error tells you, this is invalid. What you are doing is the equivalent of this:

```
x, x, y, z = 1, 2, 3, 4
a, b = x, x, y, z
```

---

<sup>* Although it has a special use in the `python` interactive interpreter: the result of the evaluation of the last expression</sup>

Comment: Sorry, should've known. Just edited it so that there's more info.

Comment: @TheAznHawk It didn't help me, but I added some explanations that will hopefully help you understand what is going on.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I'm new at python and programming in general. Been working on this for hours, frustration is really piling up lol. But thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the line:

```
pile1, pile2 = _,_,pile1, pile2
```

Your code is just fine as follows:

```
_,_,pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
if pile1==0 and pile2==0:
    print("The game is over because I took the last chip.")
    print("Thanks for playing. Let's wager next time.")

compi= compPiles(pile1, pile2)
```

Comment: You're actually only discarding the first value returned by the function call. The second one is stored in `_`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I just tried it and you're right. How does _that_ work?

Comment: `_` is just another variable name, so it is like saying `x, x, y, z = 1, 2, 3, 4`. It is a convention to say, "I don't need to use this value", but you can actually use it. Although be careful: `ipython` has a special use for `_`.